# How to optimaze looping , get data from another API with lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

when i use guzzle to get data member on join to data content is so heavy, can samebody tell me how to fix it?

```
$getNewest=$this->Get(env('TestUrl').'listcast');
 if (!empty($getNewest['DATA'])) {
            foreach ($getNewest['DATA'] as $data) 
            {
                $client = New CLient();
                $reqGet = $client->get(env('MemberUrl').'user-token-member/'.$data['member_id']);
                $resGet = json_decode($reqGet->getBody(),true);
                $array['id']=$data['id'];
                $array['title']=$data['title'];
                $array['member_name'] =$resGet['DATA']['FIRSTNAME']." ".$resGet['DATA']['LASTNAME'];
                $array['avatar'] = $resGet['DATA']['MEMBER_IMAGE'];
                $array['desc'] = $data['desc'];
                $newest[] = $array;
            }
        } else {
            $newest = array();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is the reason for its low speed, but there are some modifications that you should apply on your code.

1. Don't use `env()` in your code. Instead define a config file for example *connection.php* in config folder and set your configs in it, because config file will be cached in your production server by laravel. You can cache config by running `php artisan config:cache`
   For example *config/connection.php*

```php
<?php

return [
    'test_url'=>env('TestUrl'),
    'member_url'=>env('MemberUrl'),
];
```

2. It is not required to make a new object of *Client* class in every iteration of `foreach`. You put it outside of the loop.

```php
$getNewest=$this->Get(config('connection.test_url').'listcast');
if (!empty($getNewest['DATA'])) {
    $client = New CLient();
    foreach ($getNewest['DATA'] as $data){
        $reqGet = $client->get(config('connection.member_url').'user-token-member/'.$data['member_id']);
        $resGet = json_decode($reqGet->getBody(),true);
        $array['id']=$data['id'];
        $array['title']=$data['title'];
        $array['member_name'] =$resGet['DATA']['FIRSTNAME']." ".$resGet['DATA']['LASTNAME'];
        $array['avatar'] = $resGet['DATA']['MEMBER_IMAGE'];
        $array['desc'] = $data['desc'];
        $newest[] = $array;
    }
} else {
    $newest = array();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, by using it like this, increasing the speed of displaying the data. @BABAK